# Complex JOIN query SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have two tables, kind of 'parent', 'child' as below:

[image: Parent, child tables]

I now need to join these two tables. Requirements that satisfy the join

1. If ID of 1st table matches with ID of 2nd table
2. CHILDID of 1st table matches with ID of 2nd table
3. EffectiveDate of Child's table (whose ID matches with parent table's ID) should be equal to EffectiveDate of child table (whose ID matches with ChildID of parent table)

(In the above image, the matching rows are highlighted with red and green to illustrate the above).

So, the resulting query should display rows below:

[image: Query results]

Would appreciate any pointers as to how to achieve the desired result. Thanks!

Comment: What would really help is posting ddl for the tables and dml for the sample data. Images are nearly worthless when sharing data. [Why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: So this isn't really a `JOIN` to pick data from both tables, instead it's a filter, where you only want to show some rows from the child table, dependant on some criteria which checks rules between the child and parent tables?

Comment: Also, your logic is vague and, if I've decoded well enough, actually wrong. I see no `5 / 1005 / 2004-01-01 / 90` line in your expected results, although your logic leads me to believe it should be there.

Comment: I'm going to assume the row starting with `ROWID 5` doesn't appear because there's no matching parent row with a `ROWID 5`.  On their own those rules are meaningless, so I assume that they must all be passed for a match?

Comment: RowID 5 doesn't appear because it's effectivedate  doesn't match with parent id's effective date (rowid 1  of child table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this is actually a bit odder than I first thought, but I think this is what you want.  It might not be the cleanest way to get the results, but it's a start?

```
DECLARE @parent TABLE (ROWID INT, ID INT, CHILDID INT, FLAG CHAR(1));
INSERT INTO @parent
SELECT 1, 10, 1000, 'A'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 10, 1001, 'A'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 10, 1002, 'A'
UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 11, 1005, 'A'

DECLARE @child TABLE (ROWID INT, ID INT, EFFECTIVEDATE DATETIME, SHARES INT);
INSERT INTO @child
SELECT 2, 10, '20010101 00:00', 20
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 11, '20020101 00:00', 60
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 1000, '20010101 00:00', 30
UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 1005, '20020101 00:00', 50
UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 1005, '20040101 00:00', 90;

SELECT DISTINCT
    c1.*
FROM 
    @child c1
    INNER JOIN @parent p1 ON p1.ID = c1.ID
    INNER JOIN @child c2 ON c2.ID = p1.CHILDID
WHERE
    c2.EFFECTIVEDATE = c1.EFFECTIVEDATE
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT
    c2.*
FROM 
    @child c1
    INNER JOIN @parent p1 ON p1.ID = c1.ID
    INNER JOIN @child c2 ON c2.ID = p1.CHILDID
WHERE
    c2.EFFECTIVEDATE = c1.EFFECTIVEDATE
ORDER BY
    1;
```

Results:

```
ROWID   ID      EFFECTIVEDATE           SHARES
1       11      2002-01-01 00:00:00.000 60
2       10      2001-01-01 00:00:00.000 20
3       1000    2001-01-01 00:00:00.000 30
4       1005    2002-01-01 00:00:00.000 50
```

Yes, and those `DISTINCT`s are probably overkill?